# FILE* stream behavior in linux environment

Tags: c, linux, stream, pipe

I wonder about some question, but I couldn't google the answer. When I use fdopen() on pipe's file descriptor, will all data which is written on the other end of the pipe automatically be put into FILE* stream (by the kernel), the C code could be like these:

```c
...
char* buf = NULL;
FILE* stream = fdopen(dup(pipefd[0]), "r");  
/*read 1 C-string from the pipe, 
another data will be buffered in the stream's buffer */
getline(&line, &len, stream);
...
...
/* It's from another process */
write(pipefd[1], somebuf, strlen(sumbuf));
...
...
/*Back to original process*/
getline(&line, &len, stream);
```

Will this *getline()* call get *somebuf* content automatically or I have to *close()* and *open()* the stream again or use *fread()* to read it so the stream's buffer get updated with new data? Thanks!

Comment: It should work fine. The duplicated file descriptor from `dup(pipefd[0])` will be automatically closed when you call `fclose(stream);` but that will not close the "read" end of the pipe unless it is the last among the original and duplicate file descriptors to be closed. The kernel does not actually know or care about standard input/output streams because those are managed by the C runtime library code in user-space.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the response! I got that fclose(stream) doesn't close the read end of the pipe. But I wonder if the data will automatically got to the FILE* stream buffer from pipe if I DON'T use fclose(stream) and fopen(stream) again?

Comment: The standard I/O code in the C runtime library will just read from the file descriptor when it needs to. Since you have duplicated the `pipefd[0]` descriptor, you could even open a new stream on the same pipe after closing the original stream, although that would discard any buffered data in the original stream's buffer. (Any data that the standard I/O code has read from the pipe into the stream's buffer, but has not been read from the stream by the application will be lost when the stream is closed.)

Comment: Ok, thatnk you, I got that thing with losing data when closing the stream, but I'm more interested in another thing - in the first sentense you've said: "The standard I/O code in the C runtime library will just read from the file descriptor when it needs to." What does "when it needs to" mean exactly - will the std C lib stream code automatically read from the pipe descriptor when I put some data to the pipe from another end?

Comment: The stdio code isn't aware of the other end of the pipe. When it reads from the pipe depends on the stream's buffering. If the stream's "ungetc" buffer is empty and the stream is either unbuffered or its main buffer is empty, then it will need to read more data from the file descriptor to continue processing the current standard I/O function (such as `fgetc`, `fgets`, `fread`, `scanf`, `getline` or whatever). If the pipe is empty (and not EOF) and is in "blocking" mode (which it ought to be for standard I/O usage), then the `read()` call will block until the pipe becomes non-empty or EOF.

Comment: Thank you! I think i sutisfied my curiosity.